# What happens to the shielding of the proton when an alcohol is oxidized?

Tags: homework, nmr-spectroscopy

The full question:

> For H-NMR, the magnetic field experienced by a hydrogen atom can be
>   externally applied or internally induced or some combination of the
>   two. When the applied and induced fields act in concert, a proton in
>   these fields is said to be deshielded. Which of the following
>   processes will result in the greater deshielding of the proton? Please
>   choose from one of the following options:
>
> 1. Removing nearby carbonyl groups
> 2. Adding electropositive atoms like silicon
> 3. Oxidation of primary alcohols with $\ce{KMnO4}$
> 4. Reducing terminal alkyne groups

This is what the question is asking me, but I'm confused because if you oxidize a primary alcohol, this gives an aldehyde or a carboxylic acid (depending on reaction conditions), and the proton in question goes into forming water. So if an H disassociates, does this equate to a total deshielding, or how is this explained with respect to proton NMR? 
I realize that water does show up on NMR spectra, but I'm unclear what I am being asked. It also obviously depends if this is primary, secondary, or tertiary alcohol.

The answer given is (3) Oxidation of primary alcohols with $\ce{KMnO4}$. I don't understand why.

Comment: Is the question really asking about the shielding of a H attached to the carbon that is alpha to the alcohol?  Then you'd be comparing that H to an aldehydic H.

Comment: thanks, I think this is the problem , that i dont think its asking about that specific hydrogen. I think it makes sense now. (C.A.'s and ald have alot of deshielding)

Comment: Can you give some background on the question? It *seems* like a follow-up question, a question about a particular proton on a particular molecule, or at least a question with *some* information leading up to this question. Maybe supply a screenshot or photo of the entire question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alcohol proton becomes an acid proton. Potassium permanganate oxidizes primary alcohols to carboxylic acids. In the process, the hydroxyl proton goes from 2-5 ppm to >10 ppm (generally). Therefore, since it is shifted to a higher ppm, it is being more deshielded.